# "Vue.js and Vuetify: Error in getter for watcher 'isDark': 'TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'dark')'"

Tags: typescript, vue.js, testing, vuetify.js

I'm working on a Vue.js application that uses Vuetify for theming, and I've encountered an error that I can't seem to resolve. When I run my tests, I'm getting the following error message:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in getter for watcher "isDark": "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'dark')"
```

I've checked my component code, and I'm not explicitly using the isDark property, but it seems to be related to Vuetify's theme configuration.

Here's my component code (abbreviated for brevity):

```
<!-- CreateOrEditLocationModal.vue -->
<template>
    <!-- ... -->
</template>

<script>
import Vue from 'vue';
import Component from 'vue-class-component';

@Component({
    // ...
})
export default class CreateOrEditLocationModal extends Vue {
    // ...
}
</script>
```

I've also tried mocking the Vuetify theme in my tests as follows:

```
const wrapper = mount(CreateOrEditLocationModal, {
    // ... other options ...
    mocks: {
        $vuetify: {
            theme: {
                dark: true, // or false depending on the scenario
            },
        },
        // ... other mocks ...
    },
});
```

Despite these efforts, the error persists. I'm not sure where this error is originating from or how to resolve it.

Can someone please provide guidance on how to troubleshoot and fix this error? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which testing library you use, but with vitest when I wan't to test a component with Vuetify I do this :

```
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify';
import * as components from 'vuetify/components';
import * as directives from 'vuetify/directives';

const vuetify = createVuetify({
    components,
    directives
});

const wrapper = mount(CreateOrEditLocationModal, {
    // ... other options ...
    global: {
        plugins: [vuetify],
    }
});
```